# Are Promises in JavaScript like Exception Handling in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, exception, promise

Just like the try(), catch() and throw() in Java as an exception handling is like then() and catch() in JavaScript as a promise!? 
Just a beginner asking some questions. Please don't judge. xD

Comment: The short answer is no, not really. The long answer is, well, they are more like `Future`s in Java.  Some process executes and "promises" to either return a result or trigger and error which can be dealt with at a later stage.  The fact that promises "pass" on the error doesn't necessarily making them the same thing as `try-catch`, but is more about providing the promise chain some context as to why some condition may not have completed.

Comment: The "error" link in a promise chain is more about ensuring a smooth resolution to the call chain, in which you can resolve any issues (and know why it failed). While arguably similar, one thing that promise doesn't guarantee is whether any one of the links CAN actually generate an error, only that they "might" - basically, it's its own "error handling process"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try/catch` detect the error itself and transfer control to catch part. this syntax exists in `js` too.

but in `then/catch`, you must notify occurring an error yourself (with calling `reject`). This means you can notify `error` when you recognize an error is occurred. **that error can be a real or not real error** (programming/logical error).

Answer (score 4):

Not really.. In JavaScript we have try/catch block as well.

Main benefits of Promises in JavaScript are things like Chaining.

The equivalent of Promises in Java is **CompletableFuture**. read about :)

Answer (score 3):

No, they're quite different. Exception handling handles exceptions. Promises are a way to return values and act on them in an asynchronous environment, which JavaScript is.

Suppose you want to customize the JS confirm box. You could set up a jQuery dialog box, and return yes or no, depending on which button the user clicked. Like this:

```
function msgBoxConfirm(msgText, e) {
    e.preventDefault();               // Cancel the default behavior
    e.stopPropagation();              // Stop any other events from firing down the line
    $('#myDialogDiv').html(msgText).dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: boxTitle,
        buttons: {
            'Yes': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                return true;
            },
            'No': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now, you call your message box function:

```
var retval = msgBoxConfirm('Do you really want to do that?', e);
if (!retval) {
    //Do the no behavior
} else {
    //Do the yes behavior
}
```

What you will find is that this code will continue before it finds out the value of `retval`, so `retval` will have a value of `undefined` when you evaluate it with the `if`. This is what it means to be asynchronous; the call to your function doesn't wait until the function is done executing before it moves on, potentially causing all sorts of bad behavior.

Promises are a way of waiting until the value is returned before checking it. To see how to set up this example properly using promises, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Answer (score 1):

Promises and exception handling are different, they are not same. In javascript promises give us a away to use .**then** to know when the function has completed its execution , it helps to know when async functions have completed its execution,and javascript also provides try/catch support as you know as that of java.